# jQuery change html class when character length is lower than a specific number

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I made a jQuery snippet when I input something into a text area, the limit set by the textarea HTML input.

But what I would like to do is that as I input so many characters (with spaces), is to make the span class change as the character limit goes down to say....25.

Here's the code I worked out.

```
var maxLength = 280;
$('#tweetassistmessage').keyup(function() {
  var length = $(this).val().length;
  var length = maxLength-length;
  $('#charcterCount1').text(length);


  if  ($('#charcterCount1').text(length) < 25 ){
   $("#charcterCount1").replaceWith( "<span class=\"ui yellow circular label\" id=\"charcterCount1\"></span>" );
  } else if  ($('#charcterCount1').text(length) < 10 ){
   $("#charcterCount1").replaceWith( "<span class=\"ui red circular label\" id=\"charcterCount1\"></span>" );
  }

});
```

I tried that and the span class didn't change as I entered some text. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery's `$(selector).text(arg)` will set element's text to arg variable, and not returning anything. To count length of text, use the return of  `$(selector).text()`

Also, you have to make sure after you replace the `charcterCount1`, make sure to fill it's text (I moved `$('#charcterCount1').text(length);` to bottom)

Also, charcterCount1 needs to have initial value because `if  ($('#charcterCount1').text() < 25 ){` will return true if charcterCount1 contains empty string

Also, you need to make sure to remove the yellow/red class when the length have been reduced

Also, you need to make sure smallest number checking goes first (in your sample code, the red class is never triggered)

```js
var maxLength = 280;
$('#tweetassistmessage').keyup(function() {

  var length = $(this).val().length;
  var length = maxLength-length;
  
  if  (length == 0 ){
   $("#charcterCount1").replaceWith( "<span class=\"ui red circular label\" id=\"charcterCount1\">TOO MUCH</span>" );
  } else if  (length < 10 ){
   $("#charcterCount1").replaceWith( "<span class=\"ui red circular label\" id=\"charcterCount1\"></span>" );
  } else if  (length < 25 ){
   $("#charcterCount1").replaceWith( "<span class=\"ui yellow circular label\" id=\"charcterCount1\"></span>" );
  } else if  (length < maxLength ){
   $("#charcterCount1").replaceWith( "<span class=\"ui circular label\" id=\"charcterCount1\"></span>" );
  } 
  
  if(length != 0) $('#charcterCount1').text(length);


});
```

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="tweetassistmessage">
<span id="charcterCount1">280</span>
```

Comment: Ok, so if I add more colors? do I keep appending the `else if  ($('#charcterCount1').text() < 25 ){
   $("#charcterCount1").replaceWith( "<span class=\"ui COLOR circular label\" id=\"charcterCount1\"></span>" );
  }`? For instance, if I'm lower than 100, 50, 25, 10, or when it equals to zero (where I add another action).

Comment: @mikey186 yes, you can add more else if for that

Comment: ok I tried that, and unfortunately it's stuck at green when it's down from 100 after doing that. here's my code on link https://gist.github.com/mikey186/b1cf856fe1d210020b31628a8e1168a6

Comment: @mikey186 smallest number first (0, then 10, then 25, then 50, then 100)

Comment: oh I did the opposite. Thank you! now for the zero, is there a way to replace a zero number with a text? `if  ($('#charcterCount1').text() == 0 ){
   $("#charcterCount1").replaceWith( "<span class=\"ui red circular label\" id=\"charcterCount1\">TOO MUCH</span>" );
  }` It unfortunately just says "0".

Comment: if you do that, then you must save the real number (0) in a variable somewhere (not in html text)

Comment: would it be something like.....`var EmptyDumptyNone = 0;

  if  ($('#charcterCount1').text() === EmptyDumptyNone ){
   $("#charcterCount1").replaceWith( "<span class=\"ui red circular label\" id=\"charcterCount1\">TOO MUCH</span>" );}`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest your instead of replacing the full span code you can simply `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`.

```
<span id="charcterCount1"></span>
<textarea id="tweetassistmessage"></textarea>
```

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var maxLength = 280;
$('#tweetassistmessage').keyup(function() {
   var length = $(this).val().length;
   var length = maxLength-length;
   $('#charcterCount1').text(length)
 var limit = $('#charcterCount1').text();
  if  ( limit < 25 && limit > 10){
   $("#charcterCount1").removeClass("red").addClass( "ui yellow circular label" );
  } else if  ($('#charcterCount1').text() < 10 ){
   $("#charcterCount1").removeClass("yellow").addClass("red");
  }

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    

    <style>
        .yellow{
            background-color: rgb(220, 235, 14);
        }
        .red{
            background-color: rgb(235, 58, 14);
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body> 
   


        <form id="form1">
            <h1>Form 1</h1>
            <div><textarea maxlength="280" type="text" name="tweetassistmessage" id="tweetassistmessage" placeholder="field1"></textarea></div>
            <span class=" label" id="charcterCount1"></span>
        </form>
        <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

  
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    var maxLength = 280;
    $('#tweetassistmessage').keyup(function() {
         var length = $(this).val().length;
        var length = maxLength-length; 
        $('#charcterCount1').text(length);


        if  ($('#charcterCount1').text() < 25 && $('#charcterCount1').text()>10 ){
            $("#charcterCount1").replaceWith( "<span class=\"ui yellow circular label\" id=\"charcterCount1\">"+length+"</span>" );
        } else if  ($('#charcterCount1').text() < 10 ){
            $("#charcterCount1").replaceWith( "<span class=\"ui red circular label\" id=\"charcterCount1\">"+length+"</span>" );
        } 
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please also see that condition should be as below. Otherwise it will always go in first condition event if it is less than 10.
if  ($('#charcterCount1').text() < 25 && $('#charcterCount1').text()>10 ){

Answer (score 0):

First  declare once the `var length` and use it in your check condition ,

Also prevent wrap the span , just use `addClass`  `removeClass` to add both red an yellow class ,

the condition first should check if number is lower than yellow defined number and higher than red an so on , otherwise remove both classes ,

```
  if (length > redWarningLength && length <= yellowWarningLength) {
    $("#charcterCount1").removeClass("red").addClass("yellow");
  } else if (length < redWarningLength) {
    $("#charcterCount1").removeClass("yellow").addClass("red");
  } else {
    $("#charcterCount1").removeClass("red yellow");
  }
```

See below working snippet :

```js
var maxLength = 280;

var redWarningLength = 150;
var yellowWarningLength = 200;

$('#tweetassistmessage').keyup(function() {
  let value =  $(this).val();
  var length = maxLength - value.length;
  $('#charcterCount1').text(length);

  if(length <= 0 ) {
     $(this).val(value.substring(0, maxLength));
     $('#charcterCount1').removeClass("yellow").addClass("red").text("LIMIT EXEDED");
  }



  if (length > redWarningLength && length <= yellowWarningLength) {
    $("#charcterCount1").removeClass("red").addClass("yellow");
  } else if (length < redWarningLength) {
    $("#charcterCount1").removeClass("yellow").addClass("red");
  } else {
    $("#charcterCount1").removeClass("red yellow");
  }

});
```

```css
.circular {

  color: green;
  
}
.red {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.yellow {
  color: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#tweetassistmessage {
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea width="200" height="200" id="tweetassistmessage"></textarea>
<span class="ui circular label" id="charcterCount1">280</span>
```

Comment: @mikey186 ADDED also check limit , and prevent typing extra text after limit :) check ansswer